# TWS window does not appear to have child windows

Tags: java, tws

I am using Interactive Brokers TWS application.  I am trying write another application to enter values in the window.  To do this, I need to get the handles of the child windows.  When I look at Winspector or Spyxx, the TWS window does not appear to have any child windows.  TWS is a native Java application.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You should post on the Yahoo TWS API group - in particular you could get in touch with the author of IBController which seems to be doing a similar thing.

Comment: Good idea.  I will do that.